# I am getting API 403 error on orange data mining software while using Twitter keys

Tags: twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis using Twitter data. I got the keys and bearer token. The web site said it has ended free API Twitter version but still somehow when I signed up to the twitter developer i could get the keys. Now when I am inputting the API keys and bearer token, I am getting API 403 error. I rechecked my bearer token details, reduced the number of result searches, regenerated the tokens still the same error.

Comment: Which level of access do you have? (Free/Basic/Pro/Enterprise)